# TypeError: Module should export a function: @vue/composition-api

Tags: nuxt.js, shopware

When building the Shopware 6 PWA app based on NuxtJS, I always get the following error message:

TypeError: Module should export a function: @ vue / composition-api

Anyone here has an idea how to get it to work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloud you capture the image of the full exception message?

Comment: Also, could you provide the code of the file which is sending you this error?

Comment: I think you should ask in the slack shopware chanel there a also some core developer which anwser pretty quick

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

In nuxt.config.js make sure that your build module config is correct:

*Do not forget the `/module` at the end of it.*

```
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
]
```